# 403 Forbidden on Microsoft Teams RSC graph api calls, except on own tenant

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm working on a Microsoft Teams tab and am planning to use some of the new RSC endpoints to retrieve members of the Team/group the app has been added to.

I have followed all steps from the [RSC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent) looked at the [RSC sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-rsc/csharp/RSCDemo) but still have an issue making Graph API calls to the beta rsc endpoints.

I have listed the RSC permission in the Teams manifest:

```json
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "{AD_APP_CLIENT_ID}",
        "resource": "https://notapplicable"
    },
    "showLoadingIndicator": true,
    "authorization": {
        "permissions": {
            "orgWide": [],
            "resourceSpecific": [
                {
                    "name": "Member.Read.Group",
                    "type": "Application"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TeamSettings.Read.Group",
                    "type": "Application"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ChatSettings.Read.Chat",
                    "type": "Application"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ChatMember.Read.Chat",
                    "type": "Application"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ChannelSettings.Read.Group",
                    "type": "Application"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TeamMember.Read.Group",
                    "type": "Application"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Query Graph API like so:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{{group_id}}/channels/{{channel_id}}
Authorization: Bearer {{access_token}}
content-type: application/json
```

Where `access_token` is retrieved like so:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ad_tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={{ad_app_client_id}}&client_secret={{ad_app_client_secret}}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

When I make the GET request to a group+channel which is in the same AAD as where the AAD Application is registered it works fine and information is returned. However, when I run the exact same code on a group+channel which is in a different AD it returns `403 Forbidden`.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'TeamMember.Read.All, TeamMember.ReadWrite.All, Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All, TeamMember.Read.Group, Member.Read.Group'. Roles on the request 'Group.Selected'. Resource specific consent grants on the request ''.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-04-06T14:13:26",
      "request-id": "ce212ed2-48dc-4a8e-a7ea-4172d0cfd4c4",
      "client-request-id": "ce212ed2-48dc-4a8e-a7ea-4172d0cfd4c4"
    }
  }
}
```

The response mentions "Resource specific consent grants on the request ''." which seems to suggest it's either missing a header or another access token.
As mentioned before, this exact same code works perfectly fine when I use a group_id and channel_id from within the same AD tenant.

What other steps need to be done to get RSC calls working?

Comment: Which type of Supported account you have selected while registering the app?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT what do you mean exactly with 'type of Supported account'? An AD app setting?

Comment: Yes, azure AD app regd

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT: `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`", e.g. "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)"

Comment: We are checking internally if there is any way to get this RSC calls working. We will inform you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: We have raised a bug for this issue and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.
 Thanks!

Comment: We got update from engineering team that this is as designed.